# GET with javascript instead of PHP to track stats

Tags: javascript, php, get, statistics

I use a simple PHP script placed on each page of my websites to track some stats.

```
<?php
echo( "<img src='http://maindomain.com/stats.php?var1=" . @$_GET['var1'] . "&var2=" . @$_GET['var2'] . "&r=" . @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "' width='1' height='1' border='0' />" );
?>
```

This script works fine, once placed on domain1.com and domain2.com the file in maindomain.com/stats.php must validate the GET and register the stats.

The problem is that i also have domain3.com and this site is not PHP but simple HTML.

So i'm looking for a way to change the script in javascript, something like this:

```
<script src="http://maindomain.com/stat.php?var1=XXX&var2=YYY&r=HTTP_REFERER"></script>
```

I think this is possibile but i don't know how to pass the GET vars with js.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS instead of JavaScript.

If you create your stylesheet as such; style.css.php, you can execute php code in the stylesheet, and let the rest of the stylesheet just be as it already is.

Something like:

```
<?php 

include('stats.php')

?>

html {
color: #000
}
```

Comment: i cannot use php, neither in css. also the file cannot be include because is on external website, i'm pretty sure the only way possibile is by using js